# Unable to start the dragon-slaying quest in Whiterun

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

When you go to Whiterun in the beginning of the game to speak to the jarl who starts the quest to slay your first dragon, the quest won't start and the jarl is always in the same place every time I go to Dragonsreach. I don't want to restart the game because I'm really high into the levels

Comment: Really high in the levels? At that point in the game, aren't you like level 5?

Comment: Ya but I did not know about the quest till I was like level 15

Comment: Whoa you sidequested a lot before going to Whiterun lol.

Comment: And no I followed the quest but it's did not start the quest

Comment: Hmph. Weird. I would say to try to do 2-3 other quests, then comeback. It did debug some other quests for me.

Comment: The Jarl doesn't give you that quest.  Irileth barges in on you just as you've finished talking to the mage after taking him the stone from Bleak Falls Barrow.

Comment: @KazDragon is correct - the Jarl just reacts to the rest of the conversation, he doesn't start the quest.

Answer (score 5):

The Jarl doesn't give you the quest.  After visiting Bleak Falls Barrow for Farengar Secret-Fire (the court mage), and returning the stone tablet he requested, Irileth barges in on the conversation announcing that Whiterun is under attack.  The first dragonslaying quest follows from that.

Answer (score 0):

A tip that I would give you is to take a look if you completed the prerequisite quests before going to Whiterun for this quest.

Look here for information on what you need to do. [Dragon Rising](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Rising)

Comment: I did everything requested cus It lit me talk to the jarl but he never gave me the quest